# jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value set as an object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute, data-objects

Giving the following div:

```
<div data-options='{"name":"John", "age":"30"}'></div>
```

How to select the div element with the age equals to 30?

I tried using the .filter() method:

```
$( "div" ).filter(function( index ) {
    return $( this ).data('options').age === "30";
    //or
    //return $( this ).data('options:age') === "30";
});
```

but nothing returned.

Also tried the [:data()](https://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/) Selector for jQuery UI:
$( ":data(options).age" )
but it can only select the elements by data parameters and not by data values
(I seems to only work on elements with one simple attribute).

Finally, I tried defining the data by jQuery instead of html:

```
$( "div" ).data( "options", { name: "John", age: 30 } );
```

then trying all of the above again, but nothing returned.

Any clues on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Your first example is the correct method and works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/pdg4by0t/. Can you expand on your code, as you may have an error elsewhere in the logic

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Thank you. I figured out that I was trying to get the age as a number while it was set as a string. I thought there is no difference.

Comment: For reference, if you used `==` then it would have worked as it coerces the types. `===` compares without affecting types

Answer (score 0):

I found that, for a page with many divs, the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'age' of undefined(…)
```

was thrown when encountering a div that don't have a data-options set on it, and hence the code stops executing and searching the rest of divs in the DOM.

So, the solution is to check first if the div has a data-options set on it and then check for sub key(s):

```
$("div").filter(function(index) {
    var options = $(this).data('options');
    return options ? (options.age == 30) : false;
}).css('color', 'red');
```